# Вычисление расположения многострочного текста внутри TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-textview

Есть `TextView` с шириной и высотой, равными некоторым константам. У него внутри задан многострочный текст, каждая строка которого может иметь произвольное количество символов. Этому `TextView` динамически задаётся коэффициент масштабирования методами `setScaleX` и `setScaleY` и угол поворота методом `setRotation`. Как можно получить расположение, например, в формате `RectF`, отображаемого в этом `TextView` текста с учётом заданных масштабирования и поворота? Например, исходя из скриншота `TextView` ниже нужно получить что-то вроде `RectF(269f, 232f, 894f, 1067f)`, сам `TextView` же имеет в точности размеры скриншота.

[image: пример границ текста]